# Проблема с позиционированием блоков в bitrix

Tags: битрикс, позиционирование

Суть в чём, есть элемент со списком разделов, и маленькой демонстрацией элементов этого раздела

А именно

bitrix:catalog.section.list

```
<div class="subcategory subcategory-active animate fadeInUp" data-content="women">

<h2 class="subcategory--title">Телевизоры</h2>


<?

foreach ($arResult['SECTIONS'] as $arSection)
{
    ?>
    <a class="subcategory--item" href="<? echo $arSection['SECTION_PAGE_URL']; ?>">
        <!-- <a href="<? echo $arSection['SECTION_PAGE_URL']; ?>"> --><? echo $arSection['NAME'];?></a>

        <? $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:catalog.section",
"recommend",
array(
    "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
    "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "-",
    "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "Y",
    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
    "ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
    "AJAX_MODE" => "Y",
    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
    "BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
    "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/basket.php",
    "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
    "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    "COMPATIBLE_MODE" => "Y",
    "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
    "CUSTOM_FILTER" => "",
    "DETAIL_URL" => "",
    "DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_COMPARE" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
    "ENLARGE_PRODUCT" => "STRICT",
    "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
    "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
    "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE_OFFERS" => "N",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "2",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
    "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
    "LABEL_PROP" => array(),
    "LAZY_LOAD" => "N",
    "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "4",
    "LOAD_ON_SCROLL" => "N",
    "MESSAGE_404" => "",
    "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",
    "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить",
    "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",
    "MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE" => "Подписаться",
    "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",
    "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
    "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
    "OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES" => array(),
    "OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array("",""),
    "OFFERS_LIMIT" => "5",
    "OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array("",""),
    "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
    "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
    "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
    "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
    "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
    "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
    "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",
    "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "4",
    "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",
    "PRICE_CODE" => array("BASE"),
    "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
    "PRODUCT_BLOCKS_ORDER" => "price,props,sku,quantityLimit,quantity,buttons",
    "PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE" => "N",
    "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
    "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array("SPECIALOFFER"),
    "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
    "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "quantity",
    "PRODUCT_ROW_VARIANTS" => array(),
    "PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION" => "Y",
    "PROPERTY_CODE" => array("",""),
    "PROPERTY_CODE_MOBILE" => array(),
    "RCM_PROD_ID" => $_REQUEST["PRODUCT_ID"],
    "RCM_TYPE" => "personal",
    "SECTION_CODE" => "",
    "SECTION_ID" => $arSection["ID"],
    "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
    "SECTION_URL" => "",
    "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array("",""),
    "SEF_MODE" => "N",
    "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "N",
    "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
    "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "N",
    "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "N",
    "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
    "SET_TITLE" => "N",
    "SHOW_404" => "N",
    "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "Y",
    "SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP" => "N",
    "SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "N",
    "SHOW_FROM_SECTION" => "N",
    "SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY" => "N",
    "SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "N",
    "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
    "SHOW_SLIDER" => "Y",
    "SLIDER_INTERVAL" => "3000",
    "SLIDER_PROGRESS" => "N",
    "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
    "USE_ENHANCED_ECOMMERCE" => "N",
    "USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION" => "N",
    "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
    "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",
)
);?>


    <?

}
?>
```

В него соответственно вложен bitrix:catalog.section

```
            <div class="layout--goods layout--row mixitUp--container">
                <?
            foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as $key => $item)
            {
                if(!empty($item["OFFERS"]))
                {
                    $product = $item["OFFERS"][0];
                    $collectItem[] = $item["OFFERS"][0]["ID"];  
                }
                else
                {
                    $product = $item;
                    $collectItem[] = $item["ID"];
                }
                ?>
        <div class="layout--col layout--col-sm-6 layout--col-lg-4" style="width: 25%;">

            <div class="goods animate fadeIn" style="overflow:visible">

                <div class="goods--label">

                    <div class="goods--action">Акция</div>
                    <div class="goods--installment"></div>

                </div>
                <a class="goods animate fadeIn" href="<?=$item['DETAIL_PAGE_URL']?>">
                <div class="goods--imgWrapper">

                        <?
                        if(isset($product['PREVIEW_PICTURE']) && !empty($product['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC']))
                        {
                        ?>
                            <img class="goods--img" src="<?=$product['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC']?>" alt="<?=$item['NAME']?>">
                        <?
                        }
                        else if(isset($product['DETAIL_PICTURE']) && !empty($product['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC']))
                        {
                        ?>
                            <img class="goods--img" src="<?=$product['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC']?>" alt="<?=$item['NAME']?>">
                        <?
                        }
                        ?>

                    <!--<div class="eye"></div>-->

                </div>
                <div class="goods--name"><?=$item['NAME']?></div>
                <div class="goods--price goods--price-old"><?=number_format($product['MIN_PRICE']['VALUE'], 0, '.', ' ')?></div>
                <div class="goods--price goods--price-new"><?=number_format($product['MIN_PRICE']['DISCOUNT_VALUE'], 0, '.', ' ')?></div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <?
        }
        ?>
            </div>

        </div>
```

А так выглядит index.php

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Интернет-магазин");
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:main.include",
"",
Array(
    "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
    "PATH" => "/include/slider.php"
),
false,
Array(
'ACTIVE_COMPONENT' => 'Y'
)
);?> <!-- SUBCATEGORY --> <!-- BANNER HISTORY --> 
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:main.include",
"",
Array(
    "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
    "PATH" => "/include/banner_history.php"
),
false,
Array(
'ACTIVE_COMPONENT' => 'Y'
)
);?>
 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:catalog.section.list",
"section_main",
Array(
    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    "COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "Y",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "2",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
    "SECTION_CODE" => "",
    "SECTION_FIELDS" => array(0=>"",1=>"",),
    "SECTION_ID" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"],
    "SECTION_URL" => "",
    "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array(0=>"",1=>"",),
    "SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "Y",
    "TOP_DEPTH" => "2",
    "VIEW_MODE" => "LINE"
)
);?>


?><?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Суть вопроса в том, что я уже битый час пытаюсь позиционировать этот блок. НО
Почему то всегда в конец блока, который выводится приложением в индексе, помещается всё остальное содержимое индекса.

Прошу помощи, вроде проблема детская, а сижу уже часа 3 мучаюсь. Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил наглядное пояснение проблемы

Comment: Проще будет дать ссылку на страницу и скриншот блока который вы хотите позиционировать, по кускам кода php и html сложно вам помочь.

Comment: Добавил наглядное пояснение проблемы